# How to find in a folder the newest file following a pattern but also excluding some files

Tags: c#, linq, file

I know that this code works for finding the newest file

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(tbxDir.Text);
if (Directory.Exists(tbxDir.Text))
{
    var NewestFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles() orderby f.LastWriteTime descending select f).First();
    ...
}
```

What I can't imagine is how to extend it to:

1. Use a pattern: e.g. a*c.txt
2. Exclude a list of files (e.g. lst =  { "log.txt", "ccc.txt", ...}

Can that be done with a Linq expression?
Thanks for helping
Patrick

Comment: you can add where conditions to your clause to include file names that meet any criteria you like.

Comment: Also, `GetFiles` allows you to pass a wildcard search pattern. Your example isn't exactly clear, however, since the files you want to exclude will be excluded with the sample pattern anyway, so there is no point.

Comment: And you can just use `if (directory.Exists)` as your `if` condition rather than calling the static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetFiles` allows you to pass a search pattern for finding files:

```
var newestSearchPatternFile = directory
    .GetFiles("a*c.txt")
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
    .First();
```

And you can also use `.Where` to filter the results:

```
var filesToExclude = new[] {"log.txt", "ccc.txt"};

var filteredResults = directory
    .GetFiles()
    .Where(f => !filesToExclude.Contains(f.Name))
    .ToList();
```